# Show that by setting ${dy\over dx} = p$ , $\;{d^2x\over dy^2} = -{d^2y\over dx^2} \Big/ \left({dy\over dx}\right)^3$

Tags: calculus

If y is a function of x. Show that By setting ${dy\over dx} = p$ ,

$${d^2x\over dy^2} = -{d^2y\over dx^2} \Big/ \left({dy\over dx}\right)^3$$

Here's what I have done so far:

$${dy\over dx} = p$$

The confusion begins from here since $x$ is not defined explicitly.

$${dx\over dy} = \frac 1p$$
$${d^2x\over dy^2} = -p^{-2} \cdot {dy\over dx} = {-dy\over dx} \Big/ p^2 = -{dy\over dx} \Big/ \left({dy\over dx}\right)^2$$

I dont know where am wrong.

Comment: Hang on a sec, even after dividing some of those realtion into $1$, you can't find the derivative wrt $y$ on $p$ without knowing more about $p$. For example, is $p=p(y)$? Or $p=p(x, y)$ or $p=p(x, y)$?

Comment: What is $p$? A constant? Function? You're assuming that $p' = y'$...

Comment: What do you mean with $$\frac{dy^3}{dx}$$?

Comment: actually (dy/dx)^3 @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: @AndrewLi i think p should be a function with information on x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y = p(x)$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = p'(x)$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = p''(x)$

now,

$\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac1{p'(x)}$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2} = -\dfrac1{(p'(x))^2}\cdot p''(x)\cdot \dfrac{dx}{dy}$

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2} =-\dfrac1{(p'(x))^3}\cdot p''(x) $

$\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2} = -\dfrac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{(\frac{dy}{dx})^3}$

Comment: having issues with on the sixth line. can you make more clear pls?

Comment: the one where we find $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}= -\frac1{(p'(x))^2}\cdot p''(x)\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}$?or  the one below it?

Comment: yes this ... $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}= -\frac1{(p'(x))^2}\cdot p''(x)\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}$

Comment: $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac1{p'(x)}$ When you differentiate , you need  to use the [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)  . Giving us $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}= -\frac1{(p'(x))^2}\cdot p''(x)\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}$